# Docker-compose.yml problems of configuraion

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm a french dev...

I have a problem with the config file docker-compose.yml...
When i enter docker-compose up they show me:

```
Pulling db (postgresql:9.4)...
ERROR: The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.

Continue with the new image? [yN]y
Pulling db (postgresql:9.4)...
ERROR: pull access denied for postgresql, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  hello-world:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - "3000:8080"
    env_file:
      - database.env
  db:
    image: postgresql:9.4
    ports:
      - "5432:8080"
    env_file:
      - database.env
```

Please if someone can help me...

Comment: The [Docker Hub PostgreSQL image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) is just named `postgres:9.4`, not `postgresql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the image name. It should be `postgres:9.4` not `postgresql:9.4`